# how to search with user inputs and show result in the same page in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have developed a page to search from database with sp by user inputs and after that the result shows in the same page in a gird .  view is as below

```
<div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 mb-1">
                                <fieldset class="form-group">
                                    <br />
                                    <a onclick="GetSellerProduct()" class="btn btn-success col-md-12">Search </a>

                                </fieldset>
                            </div>


     @if (Model.productsDtos != null)
{
    <table class="table" role="grid">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>productName</th>
                <th>inventory</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.productsDtos)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.Name</td>
                    <td>@item.inventory</td>
                    <td><a onclick="GetDetail('@item.ProductId')">Details</a></td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

function GetSellerProduct() {
        var codmelli = $('#NationalCode').val();
        var postData = {
            'CodMelli': codmelli,
        };
        $.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "GET",
            url: "Lookup",
            data: postData,
            success: function (data) { }

        });

    }
```

and action as below:``

```
    public  IActionResult Lookup(SellerProductsViewModel model, string CodMelli)
    {
        if(CodMelli!=null)
        {
            model = new SellerProductsViewModel
            {
                productsDtos = _service.lookup(CodMelli)

            };
        }
       
        return View(model);
    }
```

after click on search button and doing lookup action , search result doesnt show in the table

Comment: Did you trace your action?

Comment: Can you share your `GetSellerProduct()`?

Comment: yes i traced it mutiple times

Comment: Can you get  data of `SellerProductsViewModel model, string CodMelli` in `Lookup`?

Answer (score 0):

Before go to your point, I think using HTTP POST method for lookup is largely unusual. Typically GET.

For you original question, connect to server without updating the DOM/webpage needs to be done using javascript-based solution (aka frontend). Most basic one is to send ajax request but there are other solutions:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/here-is-the-most-popular-ways-to-make-an-http-request-in-javascript-954ce8c95aaa/